# Automatically install VSIX dependencies

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have created a visual studio extension (vsix) which has dependency on Nuget Package Manager. Currently installation fails if Nuget package manager is not installed on target machine. Is there a way to automatically install dependencies with vsix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to do that. The nearest thing you have is a "location" field, but that's not used for auto-download (and doesn't even seem to be shown to the user.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Problem is the the error window does not even show what dependency is missing. It shows some generic error. User has to open the log to know the exact reason.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the experience is terrible.